# NHibernate left join two collections with QueryOver and Future

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have the Project entity and ProjectRole and ProjectUser entities:

```
public class Project {
    ...
    public virtual IList<ProjectRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ProjectUser> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectRole {
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectUser {
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

User can be assigned to Project either via his RoleID or specifically by his UserID.

I would like to get all projects that fulfill either of two requirements:
**User is in the Role assigned to Project** (Roles collection) or **User is assigned directly to the project** (ProjectUsers)

I discovered that i can't do two left joins because "cannot fetch multiple bags":

```
ProjectRole prAlias = null;
ProjectUser puAlias = null;
var projects = s.QueryOver<Project>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(p => p.Roles, () => prAlias)
    .Left.JoinAlias(p => p.ProjectUsers, () => puAlias)
    .Where(p => p.DeletedDate == null)
    .And(() => puAlias.UserID == loggedUserID)
        Restrictions.Or(
            Restrictions.On(() => prAlias.RoleID).IsIn(userRoles),
            Restrictions.Where(() => puAlias.UserID == loggedUserID)
        );
```

I tried to do this with two separate Queries and Future:

```
var projectsForUserRoles = s.QueryOver<Project>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(p => p.Roles, () => prAlias)
    .Where(p => p.DeletedDate == null)
    .And(() => prAlias.RoleID).IsIn(userRoles))
    .Future();


var projectsForUser = s.QueryOver<Project>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(p => p.ProjectUsers, () => puAlias)
    .Where(p => p.DeletedDate == null)
    .And(() => puAlias.UserID == loggedUserID)
    .Future();

var projects = projectsForUserRoles.ToList();
```

But in this way I only get results from **projectsForUserRoles** query, and not **projectsForUser**. Both queries work OK separately - first one returns 3 records, second one 2 records. What I would like to get is sum of those (5 records) with Distinct result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProjectID, p.ProjectName FROM
Projects p
LEFT JOIN ProjectRoles pr ON pr.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
LEFT JOIN ProjectUsers pu ON pu.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
WHERE p.DeletedDate IS NULL
AND(
    pr.RoleID IN (SELECT ur.RoleID FROM UserRoles ur WHERE ur.UserID = 1) 
    OR pu.UserID = 1
)
```

What am I missing? How should I link two Queries over the same Entity `Project`?

Comment: Have you tried `projectsForUser.Union(projectsForUserRoles).ToList()` overriding hash code and equals methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to finish the work in-memory? For your case it looks sensible to me.

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

var projects = projectsForUserRoles.Union(projectsForUser).ToList();
```

That is what suggests Najera [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846475/nhibernate-left-join-two-collections-with-queryover-and-future#comment76695136_44846475), but no need to care about overriding `GetHascode` and `Equals` just for this case: the first level cache will ensure you will get identical references for same entities.

Now it looks strange to me the "more than one bag" limitation kicks in while you are just filtering on them. But the message tells you are fetching. I do not know [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) much and so can not help you changing it for only filtering, not fetching.

With [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) I would instead write:

```
using System.Linq;
using NHibernate.Linq;

// ...

var projects = s.Query<Project>()
    .Where(p => p.DeletedDate == null)
    .Where(
        p => p.ProjectUsers.Any(pu => pu.UserID == loggedUserID) ||
            p.Roles.Any(pr => userRoles.Contains(pr.RoleID)))
    .ToList();
```